# Kerberos kadmin service error

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, mit-kerberos

I need to setup kerberos security , but while running kadmin service i am getting following error.

```
service kadmin start
Starting Kerberos 5 Admin Server: kadmind: Cannot set GSS-API authentication names.[FAILED]
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you give it the exact filename and put it here the principals of the keytab?

```
ktadd -k /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab kadmin/admin kadmin/changepw
```

Answer (score 0):

Type kinit and then type the password for the current user to initiate the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/krb5.conf. Leave only default_realm in libdefaults and try again:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
```

Answer (score -1):

Facing same problem.
It seems direct command "/usr/sbin/kadmind -P /var/run/kadmind.pid" runs well